# How do I arrange my desktop icons in rigidly alphabetical order?

Tags: windows, desktop, icons, sorting

Currently, my desktop icons are divided into three groups:

1. Upper left icons in the following order:

   - Libraries
   - Computer
   - Recycle Bin
   - Network Magic
2. Continuing to read downwards and to the right: about 2/3rds of the icons in alphabetical order Acrobat to WS FTP Pro
3. Continuing to read downwards and to the right: the remaining 1.3 of the icons in alphabetical order.

I want to have Acrobat in the upper left and WS_FTP Pro in the lower right with all icons in pure alaphabetical order between. How can I do this?

Comment: hint: you can actually disable auto-arrange and do it yourself if you are so obcessive compulsive...

Comment: I used to love having all my icons in order, but windows always decided to rearrange the, now... I just have myComputer and use the Windows Start (Vista/7) To search for i want.. what an improvement that is. and nice clean desktop!

Answer (score 5):

You might be looking for [Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/), which is a program that helps you organize your desktop (free for personal use).

[image]